# Server error: Connection reset by peer | End of script output before headers

Tags: apache, centos, php-7.1, xenforo, fcgid

My server:

- CentOS
- Webserver: Apache 2.4.26 and Php 7.1.9, runing **Server MPM: event**; use **mod_fcgid**.

I run Xenforo, but It cannot create new thread! Every action create new thread have out put error in PHP logs:

```
[fcgid:warn] [pid 10863:tid 140645245003520] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client ] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://mywebsite.com/create-thread
[core:error] [pid 10863:tid 140645245003520] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: https://mywebsite.com/create-thread
```

And in error_log

```
[fcgid:error] [pid 9161:tid 140645850757056] mod_fcgid: process /usr/local/safe-bin/fcgid71.sh(11688) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

Please help me fix this proplem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved this by adding **FcgidBusyTimeout** . Just in case if anyone have similar issue with me.

Here is my settings on my apache.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.......
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```